# ControlID across office versions

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I'm trying to write a VSTO plugin for Outlook, but I want it to work across multiple versions. The ControlID for the Home tab is 'TabHome' in some versions, and 'TabMail' in others - does anyone have an idea how to properly deal with this?

Comment: Where are you referencing the `TabHome`?

Comment: In visual studio in the controlid property of the properties pane of a tab element. To make a control appear in the home tab of outlook the controlid needs to be set to tabmail in some versions of outlook, and tabhome in others. I can't seem to change based on checking version number in runtime.

Comment: You can make this a dynamic call by using ribbon XML instead of the ribbon designer. Here's an example were I dynamicly name the tab. You can use the same logic to name the home tab. https://github.com/Excel-projects/Script-Help/blob/master/VB/Ribbon.xml

Comment: So you mean it's not possible using the designer? Seems silly on MSoft's part

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function using something like this.

```
 If Application.ProductVersion.Substring(0, 2) > "14" Then ' Outlook 2010
     Return "TabHome"
 Else
     Return "TabMail"
 End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already know how to check for Product version, my problem is I can't work out how to change the ControlID at runtime. Do you have an idea?